# Is there any real phonemic distinction between semivowels and their vocalic counterparts?

Tags: phonology, semivowels

So my understanding is that semivowels are *phonetically* identical (or nearly identical) to their vocalic equivalents, and that the distinction between the two is primarily based on how they behave *phonogically.* For instance, the only difference between the close front unrounded vowel [i] and the voiced palatal approximant [j] is that [i] functions as the nucleus of a syllable (and is therefore a vowel) whereas [j] does not (and is therefore a consonant). For instance, in the syllable [ja], the [j] would be the onset consonant, with the [a] being the nucleus. But couldn't this syllable also be analyzed as having no onset, with the diphthong [i̯a] as its nucleus? Such an analysis would seem to imply that all sequences of [j + vowel] are really just diphthongs with [i] as the first vowel. Are there any languages that actually distinguish between [ja] and [i̯a]? If so, how would such a distinction be made?

Answer (score 3):

In Latin there is qui (nominative singular) and cui (dative singular), presumably something like /kwi/ and /kuj/ respectively.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The OP doesn't deny that the sequences are phonologically different .

Answer (score 1):

The conventional phonological difference between the glides [j,w] and [i,u] is that the former is a consonant and the latter is a vowel, in the sense of "not a syllable peak" versus "is a syllable peak". In pre-autosegmental theories of representation, glides are [–syllabic] and vowels are [+syllable], and "syllabic consonants" like [r̩] are also [+syllabic].

In post-SPE theories, vowels are typically distinguished from consonants by choice of some dominating structure, for example "C" versus "V" in Clements & Ford's CV theory, or else as head of N versus non-head in e.g. Levin's X-bar theory. The best that moraic theory can do is posit that if it's dominated by μ it is a vowel and otherwise (if it is directly dominated by σ) it is a consonant = [j,w]. I should also point out that many practicioners of moraic theory (starting with Hyman) redefine "consonantal" to be the equivalent of SPE's feature [syllabic], so that glides are consonantal and vowel of non-consonantal.

Given all of these representational elements, one has a lot of freedom as to how on might represent a given sequence of segments. If you hear something that might reasonably be transcribed as [ja], there are indeed two prima facie plausible analyses: onset [j] plus nucleus [a], or bisegmental monosyllabic nucleus [ia] – a diphthong. If the rules of the phonology include something like "schwa deletes before a vowel of the glide-vowel sequence [ja]", you have a good argument for calling that sequence a "diphthong".

One has to pay close attention to the evidence, if any, that an author gives to justify their transcription. For example, is there a contrast between [ie] and [je], or is their distribution predictable (the former always being preceded by a consonant, the latter by a vowel or Ø)? To check the sufficiency of that evidence, one should also check whether for example there is a contrast between [ie] (one syllable) and a bisyllabic sequence [i.e].

Comment: Thx for the answer. Just one question: how would [ie] and [je] be contrasted? And are there any languages that are known to have this distinction?

Comment: I'd say German has such kind of contrast, albeit marginally: *Yacht* [yaxt] vs. *I-8* [i.axt] where *I-8* is kind of a building identifier or proper name, or *je* [je] vs. *I E* [i.e] where *das I-E* refers to a spelling pecularity of the German orthography.

Comment: The difference [je] vs. [i.e] is well enough attested, but I can't put my finger on a language where monosyllabic [ie] vs [je] is contrastive. North Saami has distinction within a syllable between [je] and [ie] but [je] is always syllable-initial and [ie] is always precede by an onset consonant.

Comment: @user6726 Finnish (and I would guess probably Sami as well) does have the distinction word-initially, though. Within a word cases like _marja_ ‘berry’ and _Maria_ are minimal pairs, but can be syllabified differently; initially, the only real minimal pairs I can see would be _ies_ ‘yoke’ and _jes_ ‘yes’, but the latter is a loan word. There are inherited words beginning in both _ie-_ and _je-_, though.

Comment: Not in N.S, but it sounds like Finnish would be a case not reducible to a syllable-count difference.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica/ Definitely marginal. But how about "i a" (hee haw) vs."ja" (yes)?

Comment: @fdb Your example is of the more rustic kind, but definitely marginal, too.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an erroneous, but there are no such counterparts, as [i] and [j], or [u] and [w]. Phonemically (i.e. in //), yes, but phonetically is no. This is the rare thing in languages, the cardinal vowels itself (especially for the /i/ vowel - in most languages it is not so high, and sometimes is retracted - [i̞~i̞˗]. So more correct to say that there are [ɪ] and [ɪ̯]/[j], [ʊ] and [ʊ̯]/[w] counterparts (n.b. phonemically is still /i/-/j/, /u/-/w/).

Comment: There are exceptions, like Spanish language, where allophonic realisation of /i/ both [i] and [ i̞ ], and the [ai̯] diphthong is possible.